# Is there any method to add draggable and droppable component to a panel

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs

Is there any method to add draggable and droppable component to a panel in sencha var op1=new

```
Ext.util.Draggable('op1',{
                group:'base',            
                                revert:true
            });
```

for the panel

```
var myPanel = new Ext.Panel({
                    dockedItems: [myToolbar],
                    fullscreen : true,
                    items:[op1]
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like this:

```
fields = {

                    id: 'data',
                    title: '{id}',



                    items: [

                        {
                           xtype: 'textfield',    
                            name : 'id',
                            id:'slno'
                        },
                        {
                           xtype: 'textfield',    
                            name : 'q1',
                            isDroppable:true,
                            autoCapitalize : true
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield', 
                            name: 'op1',
                            draggable:true,
                            group:'invalid',
                            revert:true

                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield', 
                            name: 'ans',
                            draggable:true,
                            group:'base',
                            revert:true
                            //,style:'z-index:1'
                        }
                    ]
                };
```

Comment: But There is a problem with vaild drag and drop option probably not proper xtype for the component  how to fix it